# Using ListView in a Dialog or in another Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

My planned main Activity is going to be use the selected/clicked item of a ListView.

I guess i can both use a Dialog to put the ListView in it, or i can use another Activity to put ListView in it and communicate Activities with intent.

Which is more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Both variants are normal.
So if you decide to use `dialog`, user will click on button, and the `dialog` will be opened immediately. Behind `Activity` scene will be darkended and that's OK.
Most of `Android` apps using such pattern, if you want to give user opportunity to choose an element.

But for example `IOS` apps often opens another controller(like `activity` on `Android`) and user choosing element in new window.

So my advice will be next. It is better to use `dialogs` for such cases. You can use another `activity` if you want something like `PreferencesActivity`, and your choosing should be accessibly inside all of your app, but not only one screen(`fragment`/`activity`). And as i menthioned earlier most of apps using dialog pattern.